# How to setup NPM 'git' dependency to not download each time

Tags: git, npm

I've a NPM git dependency like this:

```
//package.json
{  ... 
    dependencies: {
        'mylib': 'http://repo.com/mylib.git#develop'
    }
}
```

Each time when `npm install` is called, NPM attempts do download whole `mylib` repository.

Is there a way to tell NPM to avoid that and still keep local copy of repository at `node_modules/mylib` up to date?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you won't find that functionality officially supported by npm itself. In fact, searching npm's docs and guides doesn't yield any results, and searching [npm's issues](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20offline) shows some light into it [partially working](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2568#issuecomment-6595842), but [not in a production ready way](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12689).

There are [a few additional options](https://addyosmani.com/blog/using-npm-offline/) to make it work, but personally I didn't try these, since I don't want to depend on anything that's not 100% reliable.

Try [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), which has offline installs [as a feature](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1840075619545360).